# Detectar cambio en dato entrada angular (input)

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo el siguiente componente **HTML**

```html
    <ng-container *ngIf="batteryActions$ | async as bateria">
          <app-suggested-actions *ngFor="let batteryAction of bateria"
          [dataActions]="batteryAction"
          [actionsSelected]="actionsSelected"
          (click)="selected(batteryAction)">
          </app-suggested-actions>
    </ng-container>
```

Es una card, que recibe 2 inputs, dataActions y actionsSelected.

actions selected por defecto es un array vacio:

```js
 actionsSelected:SuggestedActions[] = []
```

Estas card tienen un metodo llamado selected que se dispara cuando se hace click sobre una card,y recibe la card misma.
Este metodo lo que hace es fijarse si esta action esta dentro del array actionsSelected y si no está, lo agrega!

```js
  selected(actionSelected){

    let actionExist = this.actionsSelected.findIndex(action => action.id == actionSelected.id)
    if(actionExist > 0){
      this.actionsSelected.splice(actionExist,1)
      actionSelected.selected = !actionSelected.selected
    } else {
      this.actionsSelected.push(actionSelected)
      console.log(this.actionsSelected);
      actionSelected.selected = !actionSelected.selected

    }
  }
```

Es en este punto, que necesito saber como detectar que se modifico actionsSelected, para que las otras cards puedan acceder a los nuevos valores.

En el OnInit de todas estas cards, se setea una propiedad order segun los datos de entrada de este input, claro,a lo primero como no hay ninguan seleccionada esta propiedad esta como null, pero cuando se selecciona una necesito que las demas actualicen ese dato de entrada.

**HTML CARDS:**

```html
<mat-card class="actionCard" [ngClass]="{'actionCard-selected': dataActions.selected}" (click)="changeOrder()">
  <mat-card-content>
        <img [src]="dataActions.url_imagen | errorImage" class="actionCard__img" alt="Photo {{ dataActions.name }}"/>
    <mat-card-title>{{ dataActions.name }}</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
{{order}}
```

**TS CARDS:**

```js
export class SuggestedActionsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  dataActions: SuggestedActions;

  @Input()
  actionsSelected: SuggestedActions[];

  order:number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let actionExist = this.actionsSelected.findIndex(action => action.id == this.dataActions.id)
    this.order = actionExist >= 0 ? actionExist : null
  }


  changeOrder(){
    setTimeout(() => {
    let actionExist = this.actionsSelected.findIndex(action => action.id == this.dataActions.id)
    this.order = actionExist >= 0 ? actionExist + 1 : null
    }, 100);
  }

}
```

Probe con OnChanges, pero no detecta.

Al hacer click en una card, reviso si en el array actionsSelected ya existe esta card entonces obtengo el indice y se lo asigno a la propiedad order, con el metodo changeOrder() del click, esto me funciona pero para actualizar una card, las demas parecen no enterarse de que cambio actionsSelected.

Le hice click a 3 cards, en orden y se puso correctamente el orden como veran en la imagen, 1, 2 y 3.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero ahora, si toco la 2, deberia la 3 pasar a tener el orden 2 ya que la otra no existe mas en actionsSelected, de hecho actionsSelected paso a tener solo 2 elementos.

```js
export class SuggestedActionsComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {

  @Input()
  dataActions: SuggestedActions;

  @Input()
  actionsSelected: SuggestedActions[];

  order:number;

  constructor(private changeService:ChangeOrderActionsSelectedService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.changeService.change$.subscribe(() => this.changeOrder())
  }


  changeOrder(){
    let actionExist = this.actionsSelected.findIndex(action => action.id == this.dataActions.id)
    this.order = actionExist >= 0 ? actionExist + 1 : null
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.changeService.change$.unsubscribe()
  }


}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Crea un servicio con un observabe que servirá para comunicar todos los componentes:

   ```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

   @Injectable()
   export class ChangeService {
   change$ = new BehaviorSubject(null)
   }
   ```
2. Inyecta ese servicio y úsalo para notificar a los demás componentes para que actualicen su estado:

   ```
   export class SuggestedActionsComponent implements OnInit {

   @Input()
   dataActions: SuggestedActions;

   @Input()
   actionsSelected: SuggestedActions[];

   order:number;

   subscription: Subscription // variable para guardar la suscripción

   constructor(private changeService : ChangeService) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {

     this.subscription = this.changeService.change$.subscribe(() => this.changeOrder())
   }
   ngOnDestroy(){
      this.subscription.unsubscribe()
   }


   changeOrder(){

     let actionExist = this.actionsSelected.findIndex(action => action.id == this.dataActions.id)
     this.order = actionExist >= 0 ? actionExist + 1 : null

    }

   }
   ```

Puedes notificar el cambio desde el método `selected`:

```
selected(actionSelected){

    let actionExist = this.actionsSelected.findIndex(action => action.id == actionSelected.id)
    if(actionExist > 0){
      this.actionsSelected.splice(actionExist,1)
      actionSelected.selected = !actionSelected.selected
    } else {
      this.actionsSelected.push(actionSelected)
      console.log(this.actionsSelected);
      actionSelected.selected = !actionSelected.selected

    }
    // notificar a los demás componentes que deben actualizarse
    this.changeService.change$.next()
  }
```

Comment: Gracias lobo, para que no quede pegado el observable, en que momento tengo que desuscribirme?

Comment: En el this.changeService.change$.next() , me pide un argumento el next, le paso simplemente un true?

Comment: Cierra la suscripción en el `ngOnDestroy()`. Y sí, pásale un `true` al `next()`.

Comment: Funciona, pero no puedo usar el unsuscribe en el onDestroy de "SuggestedActionsComponent" ,me tira un error.  Ahi lo subo en la descripción

Comment: Ahi subi el codigo y el error

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta. Agregué una variable para gestionar la suscripción.

Comment: Sabes que no me funciona ahora, le puse a la respuesta que estaba ok pero no me funciona. Osea ahora lo que pasa es que no actualiza los orders. Osea ponele que tenemos el 1,2 y 3.. si saco el 1, el 2 y 3 siguen quedando como 2 y 3

Comment: Creo que sigue pasando lo mismo, el objeto actionsSelected no cambia para los demas

Comment: Puede que ser que el `next()` se esté llamando en el lugar incorrecto. Revisa el flujo de la aplicación.

Comment: No entiendo donde la union entre actionsSelected y el observable.  Lo unico que se hace aca (creo) es cambiar el estado del observable cuando se hace un select, pero como esto le avisa a las otras cards que se actualizo actionsSelected

Comment: Cuando se llama a `next()` se emite un valor que llega a todos los componentes que están suscritos a `change$`. En ese momento se ejecuta el código que opera sobre el arreglo `actionsSelected`. Si todos los componentes comparten el mismo arreglo entonces debería funcionar.

Comment: Gracias lobo. Podrias revisar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/479023/no-deshabilita-checkbox-angular , es un problema con disabled